# Should I add set nocount for functions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, functions, set-returning-functions

I've been reading about the benefits for all triggers and procedures having "set nocount on" implemented unless you make use of DONE_IN_PROC.

I have a scalar-valued function that is called from an update trigger to calculate the sum of values across multiple tables.

Searching msdn and past articles, I haven't been able to find an explicit example of a function using set nocounton.

What is the impact on a function to include or exclude 'set nocount on'?
Is there a point or code smell in functions that should indicate the addition of set nocount on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functions cannot return data to a client so I can't think of any use of `SET NOCOUNT ON`. If you do try to add it a function you'll get an error. SQL Server considers it to cause a [side effect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx):

> function_body
>
> Specifies that a series of Transact-SQL statements, which together do not produce a side effect such as modifying a table, define the value of the function.

For example, the follow code throws an error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION X_JRO_TEST() 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
RETURN 1;
END;
```

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure X_JRO_TEST, Line 5
>
> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET OPTION ON' within a function.

Comment: Can a function select records and return @@ROWCOUNT?

Comment: @McNets I don't think that a scalar-valued function can, but SET NOCOUNT ON doesn't prevent @@ROWCOUNT from working.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @JoeObbish, Thanks :), after all that research, I'm disappointed in myself that I didn't just try it. :P